# Effective removing columns for QTreeView

Tags: qt4, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I use Qt 4.8.6. I have a custom tree model (based on `QAbstractItemModel`). Each node represents a computer node, it has a list of children and a list of operations. If computer node is not a leaf, then operation list is empty. This model is linked with `QTreeView`.  Computer nodes are located in the 0 column, each operation is depicted in a separate column, starting from the first one. Computer node can become unavailable, so I mark it in striked font and emit `dataChanged()`. But I also have to clear its operation list. What is effective way for it? I think that emitting `layoutChanged()` after `beginRemoveColumns()/endRemoveColumns()` is an overhead. AFAIK, removing/inserting columns should be done with root `QModelIndex`. So, what is the algorithm of removing columns in such situation? When I simply recalculated new total number of columns, called `beginRemoveColumns()`, removed inner data, called endRemoveColumns(), then the columns count in QTreeView was ok, but the cells in columns were blank for all computer nodes. Should I emit `dataChanged()` in cycle after that?

Also I noticed that using proxy model (`QSortFilterProxyModel`) was a headache when you need to insert columns (at least). I suppose that `QSortFilterProxyModelPrivate::create_mapping` stores old values of row/column count. That is why using tree model directly works fine with `beginInsertColumns()/endInsertColumns()` pair, but including proxy requires emitting `layoutChanged()` after `beginInsertColumns()/endInsertColumns()` pair.

Is emitting `layoutChanged()` after `endInsertColumns()` or `endRemoveColumns()` safe for persistent indexes?